# MeteorJS: Updating Object in Array from #each Loop

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-blaze, x-editable

I've been looking into this a lot, and I'm trying to implement a notes system within a document that can be updated using x-editable. My problem is I can't seem to be able to get the change to update the database.

I have tried using the $ operator and have searched for hours. I'm reasonably new to Meteor and am yet to be able to figure it out.

'notes' is a property in my document I am iterating over using #each, and I need to update specific notes

```
"notes" : [
            {
                    "title" : "Tarog",
                    "description" : "Unu afejufav tic kobgib kefvotet capi noma ewrekos ut ubbar icodafo tawmuvdif gotib jiebi cesvuwmu fajumpu."
            },
            {
                    "title" : "Mume",
                    "description" : "We ritop fu kevi ene wob lozivdi vibil womazla saob nut sojade jet."
            },
            {
                    "title" : "Gupgaf",
                    "description" : "Gompaphug zosku wo tocca rif hab cuvlipve hi fig ugadiche lecrup zakija."
            },
            {
                    "title" : "Sesekepo",
                    "description" : "Mockus beud bor fahab hi cepmu du wunefepe piibpup bavcan solpojol ug dajsuni was wob hinar omtigra."
            },
            {
                    "title" : "Ej",
                    "description" : "Waapvi par jid pa bo vim vawvekra huwbuprup amoil ohu ihdeni zahgipri oseruful danaru."
            }
    ]
```

Currently my JS:

```
Template.viewJob.onRendered(function () {
    $('#textArea.editable').editable({
    success: function (response, newValue) {
        Jobs.update(
            {"_id": parentID},
            {
                "$set": {
                    'notes.$.title': newValue
                }
            }
        )
    }
})
});
```

And this is the each loop:

```
{{#each notes}}
  <div class="well">
    <h3 class="whichIndex">{{title}}</h3>
      <p id="textArea" class="editable" data-type="textarea" data-mode="inline" data-placeholder="Enter text"
               data-emptytext="Click to enter text" data-rows="4">{{description}}</p>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you allow the updating from client side in jobs collection?

Comment: I have. The 'insecure' package is is currently installed. Will change in the future and will bring the code server side.

Comment: Rest of my view's js: http://pastebin.com/2HGxsude
Rest of my view's Template: http://pastebin.com/APE3pEeg

Comment: so what's the problem ?

Comment: It doesn't update the database. Pretty sure cos it can't find the property in the document. I can get it to work with other properties....but not an array of objects.

Comment: ok have you tried with index i.e get @index from template and "$set": {
                    'notes.'+str(doc_index)+'.title': newValue
                }

Comment: Can't you just call _Jobs.update({"_id": parentID},{"$set": { 'title': newValue } } );_ ?

Comment: I will give it a go this evening. Thank you all!